# Leading comma in c# causes system exception

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have to return the maximum number from a series of numbers. I have an edge case in which I may get a leading comma. How can I remove the leading comma so that the app doesn't break?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Exercises
    {
        public static void findMax()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a series of numbers: ");
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            List<string> dataSet = userInput.Split(',').ToList();

            List<int> parsedDataSet = new List<int>();

            try
            {
                foreach (string x in dataSet)
                {
                    parsedDataSet.Add(Convert.ToInt32(x));
                }
            }
            catch(SystemException)
            {
                 dataSet = String.Join(",", dataSet).TrimStart(",");  // <-- Here
            }

            var maxInput = parsedDataSet.Max();

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The maximum number within your list is: {0}",maxInput));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue should not be the leading comma, but the Empty string that split generates for the "before". Just check `String.isNullorWhitespace()`

Comment: `.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: `string.Join` returns a `string` that you try to assign to a `List<string>` and you never use `dataset` after, so your design is flawed. You only need, as mentioned by @CharlesP, to `int.TryParse` and check if the result is true to add the converted value on success.

Comment: @GSerg please enter this as an answer. This is the solution I'm implementing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string has a starting comma, then the resulting array will have its first element empty. Because you don't want those, tell `Split` to [not return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_StringSplitOptions_) empty elements to begin with:

```cs
List<string> dataSet = userInput.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue should not be the leading comma, but the empty string that split generates for the "before".

So check that string for validity before parsing. `String.isNullorWhitespace()` can do it. But it is propably better to use `TryParse()` rather then `Parse` (wich will be called by `Convert.ToInt32()`). Parse is the poster child of throwing vexing Exceptions. Wich is why `TryParse()` was added with the first Framework Update, 2.0

```
foreach (string x in dataSet)
{
  int parsed;
  bool success = Int32.TryParse(x, out parsed);
  if(success){
    parsedDataSet.Add(parsed);
  }
  else{
    //parsed has to be set by compiler rules for out.
    //So it is 0 at this. You propably do not want add it to that collection
    //Indeed the else is only here for that comment.
  }
}
```

Comment: you're missing the first parameter on TryParse

Answer (score 0):

if thats the only problem then you can do:

```
foreach (string x in dataSet)
{
    if (Int32.TryParse(x, out int x2))
        parsedDataSet.Add(x2);
}
```

Comment: @OlivierRogier hehe probably, and the Console.ReadLine, because who ever does that in a real application.

Comment: @OlivierRogier i haven't had the use case so far. You see console.ReadLine in school, but that's it. Programs that read files, or API, Web, or with GUIs yes.  But a program where someone would type something in a console? that's not user friendly and just clunky to use Imho. i'm sorry if i crush your text adventure memories with my attitude.

Answer (score 0):

**`string.Join` returns a `string` that you try to assign to a `List<string>` and you never use `dataset` after, so your design is flawed.**

**Also you must write `TrimStart(',')` because it takes a char and not a string.**

You only need, as others mentioned, to `int.TryParse` and check if the result is true to add the converted value on success:

```
foreach ( string x in dataSet )
{
  if ( int.TryParse(x, out var value) )
    parsedDataSet.Add(value);
}
```

*So you can remove the try catch.*